# Docker image build error: node-gyp: not found

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg

I am trying to build a docker Image for a nodejs application.

Dockerfile: https://backstage.io/docs/deployment/docker#multi-stage-build

My Docker build comamnd fails as below:

```
$ docker image build -t backstage .
...
...
...
9.056 warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/app/node_modules/cpu-features: Command failed.
9.056 Exit code: 127
9.056 Command: node buildcheck.js > buildcheck.gypi && node-gyp rebuild
9.056 Arguments:
9.056 Directory: /app/node_modules/cpu-features
9.056 Output:
9.056 /bin/sh: 1: node-gyp: not found"
```

However, I do have `node-gyp` installed:

```
$ which node-gyp
/Users/<USERNAME>/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node-gyp
```

Also:

$ npm ls -g

```
/Users/dheeraj.kabra/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib
├── corepack@0.18.0
├── node-gyp@9.4.0
├── npm@10.0.0
└── yarn@1.22.19
```

**ISSUE:**
So I am not sure why the docker build process complains `node-gyp` not found.

My ENV details:

- OS: MAC
- OS Version: Ventura 13.5
- Node ver: v18.17.1
- Yarn ver: 1.22.19

Comment: A Docker image build runs in an isolated environment, and can't see or use software you have installed on the host.  Can you [edit] your question to include the Dockerfile, and any other content necessary for a [mcve]?

Comment: Please find the Dockerfile referenced in the description. Unfortunately, I do not have Minimal reproducible example. It is straight from the link provided. Also, the the docker build is able to find the `yarn` command from the location but fails on `node-gyp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my first time with Docker and also with Nodejs. It turned out that the docker image which is used in the Dockerfile did not have `node-gyp` installed. Earlier, I misinterpreted this and installed `node-gyp` on my local instead.

In order to fix the issue, I performed below steps:

- Pull the docker image: `docker pull node:18-bookworm-slim`
- Run a container from it: `docker run --name test -it node:18-bookworm-slim`
- Log into the container: `docker exec -it test /bin/bash`
- Install `node-gyp`: `npm install --global node-gyp`
- Log out of the container
- Create a new image from the running container: `docker commit test`
- Tag the new image created: `docker tag b055994f1a17 node_backstage_image`
- Use this image in the Dockerfile: `FROM node_backstage_image:latest AS packages`
- Build the application Docker image: `docker image build -t backstage .`
- Create the application container from this application docker image: `docker run -it -p 7007:7007 backstage`
- All good now.